# Normalize Function Returning NaN

Tags: r

I am trying to use lapply apply to apply this function to a vector but it just returns NaN.

```
normalize<-function(object){ return((object-min(object))/(max(object)-min(object))) } 

x<-c(1,5,10)
lapply(x,normalize)
[[1]]
[1] NaN

[[2]]
[1] NaN

[[3]]
[1] NaN
```

It works fine when I use normalize(c(1,5,10)).

Comment: Why are you using lapply then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtain the correct result if you use `normalize(x)`. In that case the function receives a vector with several numbers as argument, from which a minimum and maximum value can be determined to calculate normalized values.

In contrast, with `lapply(x,normalize)` you effectively perform a loop which applies the function `normalize()` to every single element of the vector `x`. Since only one number (vector element) is passed to the function per iteration, in each case `min(x)` is equal to `max(x)`. Therefore the denominator `max(object)-min(object)` is zero at each iteration, and the division by zero yields `NaN` each time the function is called.

**Edit**

The call with `lapply` could be very useful in the case where `x` is a list of vectors. Then one can obtain the normalized version (according to the function defined in the OP) of every vector in the list `x` at once.

Here's an example:

```
x <- list()
x[[1]] <- c(1,3,9)
x[[2]] <- c(2,4,4,8)
x[[3]] <- c(1,2,3,5,8,13)
> lapply(x,normalize)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.00 0.25 1.00
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 1.0000000
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.00000000 0.08333333 0.16666667 0.33333333 0.58333333 1.00000000
```